# Pull an Image from Amazon ECR fails on Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker

[Following instructions from AWS:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html)

```
$ aws ecr get-login
```

returns command

```
$ docker login -u AWS -p password -e none https://aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, on Windows (this works on Mac) I receive error when trying to pull.

```
$ docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx
unauthorized: authentication required
```

I am using:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0-rc2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   906eacd
 Built:        Fri Jun 17 20:35:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0-rc2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   a7119de
 Built:        Wed Jun 29 10:03:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that by removing `https://` from returned command:

```
docker login -u AWS -p password -e none https://aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

to:

```
docker login -u AWS -p password -e none aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then it works...

This seems to relate to credstore on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Tom, this allowed one of our team members on Windows to use `docker-compose`!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the credential helpers: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-login-to-private-aws-repo-does-not-populate-config-json-correctly/17008/3